# One-click solution to disable auto-translation in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-translate

Why do I have to reselect the option to block automatic page translation each time I open Chrome? Even after reseting a page to it's original language, the next page I open has  auto-translation enabled again.

Is there a simple one-click method at the top of the page, or am I missing something?

FYI I clear my browser history regularly as is reccomended by computer security professionals.

Answer (score 1):

Translations can be partially or completely disabled directly in the browser settings. Go to **`chrome://settings/`** and under **Languages** you are able to manage your preferences:

[image: 0]

Also, you can try a variety of chrome extensions like:

- **[One Click Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/one-click-translate/anhjddeakbabimdgmonfbnpbainknbfa)**
- **[One-Click Translate Selection](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/one-click-translate-selec/cioclchdhgppnbpapkicbhlhbeldplld)**
- **[Quick Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-translate/gobpkdmjnhpopmpddhmhmbhkiienpfdo)**
- **[Right Click Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/right-click-translate/piojkjkndneggfaibepkmabjnkjlhlmk)**
- **[TransOver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transover/aggiiclaiamajehmlfpkjmlbadmkledi)**
- **[Mate Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mate-translate-%E2%80%93-translat/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke)**